# Bootstrap 3 datetimepicker enabledhours over riding HTML value

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I am using Bootstrap 3 datetimepicker as a timepicker only along with the enabledHours option - it works fine but I am unable to overwrite the display value of the text box it is attached to.

To call the picker I am using:

```
$('.datetimepicker').each(function() {
  $(this).datetimepicker({
    showClose: true,
    format: "HHmm",
    enabledHours: [14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
    sideBySide: true
  });
});
```

and then in my HTML I am using:

```
<div class='input-group date datetimepicker'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

As this stands it behaves as expected - however, frequently the time will already be set from PHP so something like:

```
    <input type='text' value="1600" class="form-control" />
```

In this scenario the text box always shows 1400 (or the first value in enabledHours) - the value of 1600 is respected if I process the form even though it shows 1400 and if I manually change the form to 1500, for example, it submits correctly but on display it always falls back to 1400.

Is there a way to stop this so it shows 1400 if the value is blank but shows the value when it is not?

https://jsfiddle.net/dnb2ajc8/2/

Answer (score 1):

You may set the default value when initializing datetimepicker. I'm not an expert but here is a dirty solution:

```
$('.datetimepicker').each(function() {
  $(this).datetimepicker({
    showClose: true,
    format: "HHmm",
    enabledHours: [14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
    sideBySide: true
  }).find('input').val($(this).find('input').attr('value'));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qxwa8bh0/

Comment: You beat me to posting something like this

Comment: @DiegoLópez What do you mean?

Comment: this will allow not enabledHours that come from the server, but if the server know what is doing should be ok, what does @bhttoan thinks?

Comment: I meant that I thought on posting a similar solution.

Comment: @DiegoLópez Ah, ok then. There would be more appropriate solution i think. Could you pls send your solution, i may learn something about jquery from it.

Comment: I think your answer points the main idea and is good as it is.

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATED**

You can set the default date, but this method does not use the attribute.

```
 $('.datetimepicker').each(function() {
   var date = new Date();
   $(this).datetimepicker({
     showClose: true,
     format: "HHmm",
     enabledHours: [14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
     sideBySide: true,
     defaultDate: date.setHours(15, 27, 0, 0)
    });
});
```

[This is the JSFiddle updated](https://jsfiddle.net/dnb2ajc8/5/)

Comment: Hi - when I run that the picker does not work and gives an error in console of "Uncaught TypeError: defaultDate() Could not parse date parameter: true"

Comment: The JSFiddle work, are you sure you copy the same code ? https://jsfiddle.net/dnb2ajc8/4/

Comment: @bhttoan For this answer I had read the doc, you can check it here: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#defaultdate

Comment: @Baro I don't think this is working, check the console when running your fiddle, is throwing "Uncaught TypeError: defaultDate() Could not parse date parameter: true". The defaultDate property is used for a different purpose.

Comment: The error has gone but also value in the HTML is now cleared and it is being set through JS which is not really what I had wanted

Comment: @bhttoan 
It 's true, but this would be the correct way to set the default date for this plugin (the guide and source code is nowhere to do what you ask). I prefer to enter a correct answer formally (although not precisely what you ask) that a wrong and with bug answer, or a duplicate workaround, at least for those who seek a similar question on StackOverflow . :)

Comment: The problem is there are two pickers per page (start and end time) hence the each and setting the value in JS will work for one but then not the other